# SwiftUI Charts tapping Bar Chart

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, charts, swiftui-charts

I have used the new SwiftUI Charts to make a simple bar chart, with month names on the x axis and cost on the y axis. I have added a `.chartOverlay` view modifier which tracks where I tap on the chart, and shows a `BarMark` with a text of the cost of the bar tapped.

This was very straightforward to implement, but when starting tapping on the bars, I found that tapping on the first and second bar produced the wanted result, but starting with the third bar, the bar tapped and the second bar was swapped, but the `BarMark` text showed was correct.

I have used a few hours on this problem, but can't find out what is wrong here.

The complete code is shown here, if anyone can see what is wrong:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Charts

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let months = ["Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"]
    let costs = [20.0, 40.0, 80.0, 60.0, 75.0, 30.0]
    @Published var forecast: [Forecast] = []
    @Published var selectedMonth: String?
    @Published var selectedCost: Double?

    init() {
        forecast = months.indices.map { .init(id: UUID(), month: months[$0], cost: costs[$0]) }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart(viewModel.forecast) { data in
            BarMark(x: .value("Month", data.month), y: .value("Kr", data.cost))
                .foregroundStyle(Color.blue)
            if let selectedMonth = viewModel.selectedMonth, let selectedCost = viewModel.selectedCost {
                RuleMark(x: .value("Selected month", selectedMonth))
                    .annotation(position: .top, alignment: .top) {
                        VStack {
                            Text(estimated(for: selectedMonth, and: selectedCost))
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        .chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks(position: .leading)
        }
        .chartOverlay { proxy in
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .onTapGesture { location in
                            updateSelectedMonth(at: location, proxy: proxy, geometry: geometry)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateSelectedMonth(at location: CGPoint, proxy: ChartProxy, geometry: GeometryProxy) {
        let xPosition = location.x - geometry[proxy.plotAreaFrame].origin.x
        guard let month: String = proxy.value(atX: xPosition) else {
            return
        }
        viewModel.selectedMonth = month
        viewModel.selectedCost = viewModel.forecast.first(where: { $0.month == month })?.cost
    }

    func estimated(for month: String, and cost: Double) -> String {
        let estimatedString = "estimated: \(cost)"
        return estimatedString
    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .padding()
    }
}

struct Forecast: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let month: String
    let cost: Double
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this approach, using a `ForEach` loop and having the `RuleMark` after it:

```
var body: some View {
    Chart { // <-- here
        ForEach(viewModel.forecast) { data in  // <-- here
            BarMark(x: .value("Month", data.month), y: .value("Kr", data.cost))
                .foregroundStyle(Color.blue)
        }  // <-- here
        
        if let selectedMonth = viewModel.selectedMonth,
           let selectedCost = viewModel.selectedCost {
            RuleMark(x: .value("Selected month", selectedMonth))
                .annotation(position: .top, alignment: .top) {
                    VStack {
                        Text(estimated(for: selectedMonth, and: selectedCost))
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    .chartYScale(domain: 0...100) // <-- here
    .chartYAxis {
        AxisMarks(position: .leading)
    }
    .chartOverlay { proxy in
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture { location in
                        updateSelectedMonth(at: location, proxy: proxy, geometry: geometry)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, so crazy that this is the best way to tap on a BarMark in Apple's lib...