# Swiftui Charts resorting ontapGesture with annotation

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

I have a Chart where I'm trying to add annotation for a bar when tapped. The annotation appears properly~ish. The bars start movig around to different positions once I tap on them.

Here's the code for this?

```
                        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                            GroupBox ("Recalls by state") {
                                Chart {
                                    let recallData = statsVM.getRecallsByState(with: recallMockData)
                                    ForEach(recallData, id: \.self) { barMark in
                                        BarMark(
                                            x: .value("Week", barMark.week),
                                            y: .value("Recalls", Double(barMark.count))
                                        )
                                        .foregroundStyle(Color("BorderColor"))
                                        .annotation {
                                            Text(selectedState ?? "nil?")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                .chartOverlay { proxy in
                                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                                        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                                            Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle())
                                                .onTapGesture { location in
                                                    updateSelectedState(at: location, proxy: proxy, geometry: geometry)
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                .padding()
                                .chartYAxis {
                                    AxisMarks(position: .leading)
                                }
                                .frame(width: 450)
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(height: 250)

    func updateSelectedState(at location: CGPoint, proxy: ChartProxy, geometry: GeometryProxy) {
         let xPosition = location.x - geometry[proxy.plotAreaFrame].origin.x
         guard let state: String = proxy.value(atX: xPosition) else {
             return
         }
        selectedState = state
        selectedCount = statsVM.getRecallsByState(with: coreVM.recallResults).first { $0.week == state }?.count ?? 0
     }
```

This is very similar to the following post, but the solution did not work. [SwiftUI Charts tapping Bar Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74325725/swiftui-charts-tapping-bar-chart)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I wanted to mention this anyway. If your annotation is showing up near an edge of the chart. The chart expands to accomodate it. You can solve this by setting the position to .leading or .trailing based on where it is on the chart.

```
.annotation(position: position, // This is where you want to set the position 
            alignment: .center,
            spacing: 10) {
    AnnotationPopup(value: annoValue ?? 0.0)
}
```